# Django Crispy_Form unable to render in HTML

Tags: python, django, forms, django-crispy-forms

I have been following the docs/videos online and can't seem to get my Form to render, I would be happy if someone could explain me what I am doing wrong:
My goal is to get the Form to render

Here is my Code:

**views.py**

I handled both cases according to request type and didn't leave the else block empty.
Defined the form, didn't forget the redirect

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import UserRegisterForm


def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f'Account created for {username}!')
            return redirect('')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'register.html', {'form': form})
```

**forms.py**

Defined a form from the existing Django Forms and included all the necessary fields

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm


class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
```

**register.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
<div class="content-section">
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Join Today</legend>
            {{ form |crispy }}
        </fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div class="border-top pt-3">
        <small class="text-muted">
            Already Have An Account? <a class="ml-2" href="#">Sign In</a>
        </small>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

**base.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Q&A Learning Center {% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>
<div></div>
<header>
    <!-- NavBar -->
    {% include 'partials/_navbar.html' %}
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 m-auto">
                {% block content %}{% endblock %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>

</body>
</html>
```

**main application urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('pages.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

**pages\urls.py**

from django.urls import path

from . import views

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='about'),
    path('register/', views.register, name='register'),
]
```

**pages\views.py**

```
def register(request):
    return render(request, 'users/register.html')
```

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
    'crispy_forms',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_mysql',
]
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'
```

[The result I get on the site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6RHG.png)

Tried on Chrome and Firefox

Comment: And what do you actually see?

Comment: I can see the legend,button and everything under it. I wrote some text before and after the form, I can see them without any problem too.(I have added an Image)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to get the Form to render. I am not exactly sure what specifically was the solution but what I changed is ; I've put the register.urls in the main urls file as a stand-alone app with its own urls, and properly routed to the register.html then it worked. Also changed the base.html I think there was also an error on where I displayed the site content

here is the updated code:

**myApp.urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('pages.urls')),
    path('', include('users.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

**users.urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('register/', views.register, name='register'),
]
```

**users.views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import UserRegisterForm


def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('index/')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {
        'form': form
    })
```

**base.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Q&A Learning Center</title>
</head>
<body>
<nav>
    {% include 'partials/_navbar.html' %}
</nav>
    <div class="container">
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**users.templates.users.register.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-8">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h2>Sign Up</h2>
                <form method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{ form|crispy }}
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign up</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you have a small space.

Change this.

```
{{ form |crispy }}
```

For this.

```
{{ form|crispy }}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but this didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Correct the line in your form meta class from this:

```
fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
```

To this:

```
fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion and it unfortunately didn't work.